# PTR in Assembly is redefining object and won't run

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I'm creating a really simple program in Assembly Language. To create an array with the first few fibonacci numbers in it. However on lines 53 I try to use `MOV bx,WORD PTR [fibonacciArray + 5]` and it says it's already defined the `fibonacciArray` which I have yet this is the only way I've ever seen `PTR` used.

```
 INCLUDE Irvine32.inc     ;//Includes the Irvine32 library of functions

.data
 fibonacciArray BYTE 0h,1h,0h,0h,0h,0h,0h           ;only known f(0) = 0 && f(1) = 1


 .code
  main proc

 MOV eax, 0          ;eax register is zeroed out
 MOV ebx, 0          ;ebx register is zeroed out

 MOV al, fibonacciArray             ;al = 0
 ADD al, [fibonacciArray + 1]       ;al = 1

 XCHG [fibonacciArray + 2], al      ;fibonacciArray now 0,1,1,0,0,0,0
 MOV eax, 0                         ;eax register is zeroed out
 ADD al, [fibonacciArray + 1]       ;al = 1
 ADD al,[fibonacciArray + 2]        ;al = 2

 XCHG [fibonacciArray + 3], al      ;fibonacciArray now 0,1,1,2,0,0,0
 MOV eax, 0                         ;eax register is zeroed out
 ADD al,[fibonacciArray + 2]        ;al = 1
 ADD al,[fibonacciArray + 3]        ;al = 3

 XCHG [fibonacciArray + 4], al      ;fibonacciArray now 0,1,1,2,3,0,0
 MOV eax, 0                         ;eax register is zeroed out
 ADD al,[fibonacciArray + 3]        ;al = 2
 ADD al,[fibonacciArray + 4]        ;al = 5

 XCHG [fibonacciArray + 5], al      ;fibonacciArray now 0,1,1,2,3,5,0
 MOV eax, 0                         ;eax register is zeroed out
 ADD al,[fibonacciArray + 4]        ;al = 3
 ADD al,[fibonacciArray + 5]        ;al = 8

 XCHG [fibonacciArray + 6], al      ;fibonacciArray now 0,1,1,2,3,5,8


 MOV bl,[fibonacciArray + 3]
 call DumpRegs       ;prints the register information to the screen

 MOV bh,[fibonacciArray + 4]
 call DumpRegs       ;prints the register information to the screen

 MOV bx,WORD PTR [fibonacciArray + 5]

 call DumpRegs       ;prints the register information to the screen


exit  
main endp
end main
```

Here's the error message

```
   1>------ Build started: Project: Project, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
   1>reorder.obj : error LNK2005: _main@0 already defined in fibonacci.obj
   1>C:\Users\~~~~~~~~~~\Project32\Debug\Project.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: That's not what the error says. It says `_main@0 already defined in fibonacci.obj`. Which means you've got `main` defined twice. Once in `reorder.obj` and once in `fibonacci.obj`. You probably only meant to have the later file in your project.

Comment: THANK you! I haven't worked with assembly long, obviously. Works perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

As Ross Ridge pointed out in his comment:

> It says _main@0 already defined in fibonacci.obj. Which means you've got main defined twice. Once in reorder.obj and once in fibonacci.obj. You probably only meant to have the later file in your project

The linker error you got was:

```
1>reorder.obj : error LNK2005: _main@0 already defined in fibonacci.obj
```

The way to read this is that while the linker was processing `reorder.obj` it found `main` was already defined in the file `fibonacci.obj` . For obvious reasons you can't have two labels with external (global) linkage because the linker would have no idea which label you intended to use if it was referenced in the code.

It was more than likely that you had inadvertently defined `main` twice - once in each file.